# Docker: $[npm,: not found

Tags: docker, cypress

I'm running a cypress test in a Docker container with the DockerFile below and my code is throwing the error:

```
#12 0.662 /bin/sh: 1: $[npm,: not found
```

I searched previous post about similar error, but I couldn't find any answer to my problem. How can I fix the issue?

DockerFile:

```
FROM cypress/base:16.13.0

RUN mkdir /app 
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN npm install

RUN $(npm bin)/cypress verify        


RUN $["npm", "run", "cypress:e2e"]
```

.dockerignore:

```
node_modules
```

Comment: What's the `$` for?

Comment: It should just be `RUN ["npm", "run", "cypress:e2e"]`. Accordingly, this reads to me as a typo-based question.

Answer (score 0):

You must install npm to use npm. so you could do this

1. RUN apt install sudo curl
2. RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | sudo -E bash -

then you can use npm after this